# NLog and Enterprise Solution

Tags: c#, exception, nlog, enterprise

I successfully added Nlog to my solution to log in Database , my problem now that my Enterprise solution has many classes projects plus wpf , wcf and MVC applications , and I want to centralize the log and not to repeat myself , and be forced to install Nlog per project  , any idea how to do that , am I missing something

Comment: Abstract your logging into it's own assembly, depend on the abstraction (or interface) inject the instantiation with a DI container.

Comment: 1) Install NLog for each solution using nuget.  2) Create a “global” NLog config file and copy this file to your projects using build scripts.  3) If you want to be able to replace NLog with any other logging library you should abstract it using a custom interface or something like: https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging